# FormsAuthentication.Decrypt and System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors in .NET 4.8 Web Forms + IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, webforms, forms-authentication

This has been working fine for months and just quit within the last couple of weeks. .NET 4.8 Web Forms app hosted in IIS: works fine when deployed to server, but fails locally. Two apps at virtual paths under same domain, both .NET 4.8, looks like this in IIS:

```
- domain.com
    - /virtualpath1
    - /virtualpath2
```

Virtualpath1 creates a `FormsAuthentication` cookie, and Virtualpath2 reads it.

I have the same `machineKey` values set at the domain level and at both virtual directory paths, HMACSHA256 + AES.

Just this past couple of weeks, suddenly when calling `FormsAuthentication.Decrypt` from Virtualpath2, I get the following error:

> Error occurred during a cryptographic operation:
> at System.Web.Security.Cryptography.HomogenizingCryptoServiceWrapper.HomogenizeErrors(Func`2 func, Byte[] input)
> at System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(String encryptedTicket)

I've tried clearing cookies and browser cache to no avail.  It also happens no matter what browser I use.

I'm wondering if there was a NuGet package upgrade that might have caused this to happen??

Any insight is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Did the authentication method change at server?  Many servers are switching from Windows Authentication to OAUTH2 (uses a token).  The error may be the OAUTH token and not the encryption.  OAUTH2 can be used by Windows, Linux, MAC while windows authentication can only be used in windows.

Comment: I think you've exposed what could be a problem; the original forms auth has a user log in using Windows credentials, then a forms auth cookie is created based on that login; the second app reads that forms cookie. Could something about the underlying mechanism with which Windows auth is performed have changed?

Comment: The server authentication method may of changed.  If so you need to delete the old cookies before new code will work.  The cookies may still be using the windows credentials instead of new OAUTH.